# apache 2.2 (ubuntu) won't let me set php error reporting via .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-reporting

i have a problem with my server which is running ubuntu (debian) linux and apache 2.2/php 5.2

as this is mainly a productive server, `display_errors` is turned OFF in the php.ini

for development purposes, i want to enable these error reporting stuff for certain domains. but when i set

php_flag display_errors on

in the .htaccess file of the test-domain, it simply wont work :(
so i have to set display_errors in the php.ini which affects ALL websites on the server... how can is set this locally for ONE domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide PHP directives in an `.htaccess` file unless PHP runs as Apache module. Is that the case? If so, first make sure the file is actually being read. A quick test you can do is to make a syntax error on purpose in the .htaccess file: your site should return a 500 error message. If you are running PHP as CGI, you probably have a custom `php.ini` file somewhere for each user.

Last but not least, you can enable error reporting in a per-application basis. Just add this code on top:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) enabled in your vhost? If it's set to 'None', then Apache will utterly ignore .htaccess files.